# Parse varying HTML using htmlagilitypack in C#

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I need some suggestions as to how to generalize HTML parser using htmlagilitypack with C#. The webpages that I parse contain Employee info. All of them have a) Name, ID, Address, Telephone 
Here are the fields that may or may not appear a) Email b) fax c) Working hours d) skypeid

```
Employee 1
    <table>
    <tr><td nowrap>Name</td><td class="title"><b>Amy</b></td></tr><tr>
    <tr><td nowrap>ID</td><td class="title"><b>12345</b></td></tr><tr>
    <tr><td nowrap>Address</td><td class="title"><b>36 Main St, Baton Rouge, LA</b></td></tr><tr>
    <tr><td nowrap>Telephone</td><td class="title"><b>123-456-7890</b></td></tr><tr>
    <tr><td nowrap>Email</td><td class="title"><b>Amy@yahoo.com</b></td></tr><tr>
    <tr><td>skypeid</td><td class="title"><b>oilcompany</b></td></tr><tr>
    </table>

Employee 2
    <table>
    <tr><td nowrap>Name</td><td class="title"><b>Cathy</b></td></tr><tr>
    <tr><td nowrap>ID</td><td class="title"><b>99345</b></td></tr><tr>
    <tr><td nowrap>Address</td><td class="title"><b>36 Main St, Baton Rouge, LA</b></td></tr><tr>
    <tr><td nowrap>Telephone</td><td class="title"><b>123-456-7899</b></td></tr><tr>
    <tr><td nowrap>Working Hours</td><td class="title"><b>8 PM - 6 AM</b></td></tr><tr>
    <tr><td nowrap>fax</td><td class="title"><b>123-456-1111</b></td></tr><tr>
    </table>
```

Code:

```
    HtmlNodeCollection tdNoWraps = hdoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@nowrap]");
    HtmlNodeCollection tdNoWrapsclass = hdoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@class]");
    if(tdNoWraps != null)
    {
       if (tdNoWraps[0].InnerText.Trim().Contains("Name"))
                        dr["Name"] = tdNoWrapsclass[0].InnerText.Trim();

    ....
    }
```

As you see Employee 1 is different from Employee. How can I write a generic parser? And also 'skypeid' does not have tag  it is just .

Thanks
HR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your sample, it seems that you should parse a record by “td” (label) and “td[@class]" (value) since skypeid does not contain the “nowarp” attribute.

Check this sample:

**Employee object**

```
public class Employee
{
    public string ID { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public string Address { set; get; }
    public string Telephone { set; get; }
    public string Email { set; get; }
    public string WorkingHours { set; get; }
    public string Fax { set; get; }
    public string SkypeID { set; get; }
}
```

I would simply suggest looping through the tables then inside each loop you will need to loop through all the “td” elements (in the table) and if the “td” doesn’t have a “class” defined it can be treated as the label and if it does have a “class” it is the value (at this point you save the data and move on to the next property).

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        #region "HTML"

        string t = @"<table>
<tr><td nowrap>Name</td><td class=""title""><b>Amy</b></td></tr><tr>
<tr><td nowrap>ID</td><td class=""title""><b>12345</b></td></tr><tr>
<tr><td nowrap>Address</td><td class=""title""><b>36 Main St, Baton Rouge, LA</b></td></tr><tr>
<tr><td nowrap>Telephone</td><td class=""title""><b>123-456-7890</b></td></tr><tr>
<tr><td nowrap>Email</td><td class=""title""><b>Amy@yahoo.com</b></td></tr><tr>
<tr><td>skypeid</td><td class=""title""><b>oilcompany</b></td></tr><tr>
</table>

<table>
<tr><td nowrap>Name</td><td class=""title""><b>Cathy</b></td></tr><tr>
<tr><td nowrap>ID</td><td class=""title""><b>99345</b></td></tr><tr>
<tr><td nowrap>Address</td><td class=""title""><b>36 Main St, Baton Rouge, LA</b></td></tr><tr>
<tr><td nowrap>Telephone</td><td class=""title""><b>123-456-7899</b></td></tr><tr>
<tr><td nowrap>Working Hours</td><td class=""title""><b>8 PM - 6 AM</b></td></tr><tr>
<tr><td nowrap>fax</td><td class=""title""><b>123-456-1111</b></td></tr><tr>
</table> ";

        #endregion

        var doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(t);


        var records = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table");
        List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
        foreach (var item in records)
        {
            var elem = item.Descendants().Where(m => m.Name == "td");
            var employee = new Employee();

            string elementName = "";
            foreach (var row in elem)
            {
                if (elementName == "")
                {
                    elementName = row.InnerText;
                }

                if (row.Attributes.Contains("class"))
                {
                    switch (elementName.Trim().ToLower())
                    {
                        case "name": employee.Name = row.InnerText.Trim();
                            break;
                        case "id": employee.ID = row.InnerText.Trim(); 
                            break;
                        case "address": employee.Address = row.InnerText.Trim();
                            break;
                        case "telephone": employee.Telephone = row.InnerText.Trim();
                            break;
                        case "email": employee.Email = row.InnerText.Trim();
                            break;
                        case "skypeid": employee.SkypeID = row.InnerText.Trim();
                            break;
                        case "working hours": employee.WorkingHours = row.InnerText.Trim();
                            break;
                        case "fax": employee.Fax = row.InnerText.Trim();
                            break; 
                    }

                    elementName = "";
                }
            }
            employees.Add(employee); 
        }

        foreach (var e in employees)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Name);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So each employee is in one table?
Each row in table is one attribute of employee, first column is attribute name second is actual value.
I would take shot with putting this into some Employee object like:

```
class Employee{
  string Name {get; set;}
  string ID {get; set;}
  string Address {get; set;}
  string Telephone {get; set;}
  string Email {get; set;}
  string Fax {get; set;}
  string WorkingHours {get; set;}
  string SkypeId {get; set;}
}
```

You can make it strongly typed with try parse also but for now just go with something like below.
**Some edge cases might not be covered and code probably will break, but you get the idea I think.**

```
HtmlNodeCollection tdNoWraps = hdoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@nowrap]");
HtmlNodeCollection tdNoWrapsclass = hdoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@class]");
var enumeratorNoWrapsClass = tdNoWrapsclass.GetEnumerator();
Employee employee = new Employee();

if(tdNoWraps != null)
{
 foreach (var element in tdNoWraps){
   if (element.InnerText.Trim().Contains("Name")){
                    employee.Name = enumeratorNoWrapsClass.Current.InnerText.Trim();
                }
   ....
  }
}
```